# Retrieving and displaying XML data

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I have an XML file with the following structure:

```
<item>
  <title>title</title>
  <description>description</description>
</item>
```

With my current ajax request, no results are being printed on the page, unsure why?

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'feed.xml',
  dataType: 'xml',
  type: 'GET',
  success: xmlParser,
  success: function(d) {
    console.log($(d).find('item').length || 0);
  }
});


function xmlParser(xml) {
  $(xml).find("item").each(function() {
    $("#container").append('<div class="test">' + $(this).find("title") + '</div>');
    $(".item").fadeIn(1000);
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <!-- print results here -->
</div>
```

With the above, the `container` div is empty?

Comment: `success` is assigned twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse the `xml` content using [`jQuery.ParseXML`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) and try using the `.text()` function to read the data inside the element. For sample:

```
function xmlParser(content) {
  var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(content);
  $(xmlDoc).find("item").each(function() {
    $("#container").append('<div class="test">' + $(this).find("title").text() + '</div>');
    $(".item").fadeIn(1000);
  });
}
```

See the working sample: https://jsbin.com/xayazoxela/edit?html,js,output (without the ajax request because we can't have the file on that scope).

You also have defined `success` function on your ajax request twice. Fix it (if you want to call both code) for sample:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'feed.xml',
  dataType: 'xml',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(d) {
     xmlParser(d);
     console.log($(d).find('item').length || 0);
  } 
});
```